# PHP/WordPress -- bind arguments to add_action call at bind time

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to do something like this:

```
function activate_account_callback($user_id) {
  function footer_callback() {
     // Do some stuff with $user_id
  };

  add_action('wp_footer', footer_callback);
};

add_action('bp_core_activate_account', 'activate_account_callback');
```

ie., on the `bp_core_activate_account` event I want to attach an event to `wp_footer`. The problem I'm having is that the inner function `footer_callback` doesn't seem to be able to access the `$user_id` argument passed to `activate_account_callback` (I'm not a PHP programmer and I'm not entirely sure how PHP scoping works).

So what I'd like to do is somehow create a new function that takes no arguments but that has access to the `$user_id` variable.

So the way I'd like to solve the problem boils down to wanting to do this:

```
function func1($arg) {
   echo($arg);
}
function func2 = some_magic($func1, 3);
func2(); // Should echo "3"
```

Then I could use the `func2` function and pass it to the inner `add_action`. I just don't know what the `some_magic` should be.

Or if this an inherently dumb way of doing things I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function within a function like that isn't very standard, and you don't need to do it that way anyway. Is the activated user also the user who is logged in to WordPress? It would save some effort if you could just use `wp_get_current_user()`.

If you need to carry the $user_id from one function to another, between hooks, you can't transfer it directly and the scope of the functions won't work for you. You could use globals, or use a function with a static variable.

### Using a global variable

```
function activate_account_callback($user_id) {
  global $bpcore_activated_uid;
  $bpcore_activated_uid = $user_id;

  add_action('wp_footer', activate_account_footer);
};

function activate_account_footer() {
  global $bpcore_activated_uid;
  if ( !$bpcore_activated_uid ) return;

  echo "Activated user ID: " . $bpcore_activated_uid;
}

add_action('bp_core_activate_account', 'activate_account_callback');
```

---

### (Update) Using a static variable

We'll call the target twice this way, the first time will be used just to capture the user ID. Once captured, future calls will already have the value. The only real reason you want this over a global variable is if you don't need the user ID anywhere else.

```
function activate_account_callback($user_id) {
  activate_account_footer( $user_id ); // Pass the user ID
  add_action('wp_footer', activate_account_footer);
};

function activate_account_footer($u = null) {
  static $user_id = null;

  if ( $u && !$user_id ) {
    $user_id = $u;
    return; // capture and abort
  }

  if ( !$user_id ) return; // In case we never provide the value, abort

  echo "Activated user ID: " . $user_id ;
}

add_action('bp_core_activate_account', 'activate_account_callback');
```

Notes:

1. I am not familiar with the plugin involved, but I would assume you can access the user ID through a global variable provided by the plugin. Some like `$bp` (which exists, but I do not know if it contains the ID).
2. Neither option is built to work for multiple user activations at once. If this function is used for bulk actions, you may have issues. If you need multiple user support, just switch to an array (static variable

Comment: Unfortunately at the time of account activation the user isn't actually logged in (that's a separate step) so `wp_get_current_user` isn't applicable. This answer looks like it will work and be useful though I feel one without a global variable would be better.

Comment: Global variables, despite what everyone says, are actually useful for this purpose. You need to carry a value through to a completely different part of your code. I've added a static variable option, which is uglier and has a few more lines, but no globals. Another option is using a constant with `define`, but that's not much different than a global.

Comment: Yeah you're right that it's useful and that the static variable isn't really less bad than the global variable, but a solution that just transformed a local function to get around the scoping problem would be better than both, I think.

When you say it won't work for multiple user activations at once, does that apply to race conditions if two people were to try to activate their accounts in quick succession? I don't need bulk activations. Can you elaborate on "just switch to an array" for this?

Comment: Actually I doubt that will ever even occur, unless you are an administrator and manually activate multiple accounts using the "bulk edit" option. If two users activate at the same time, from different computers, there is no problem there. It's only if you run the `activate_account_callback` function twice, on the same request, for different users.

Comment: Also, regarding global vs. static vs. local functions. It really doesn't make a difference. The correct way to do this would be for the original plugin (buddypress, is it?) to make the user ID globally accessible. So that not just your script, but also the buddypress plugin are working with the same variable. I don't see that variable in the source code though, which is what my code is for (a workaround).